# invert navbar colors past 70vh - html/css

Tags: html, css, nav, css-filters

I'm wanting to invert the color of my navbar once it goes past 70vh.

I'm thinking I need an @media with invert added to the nav container & logo saying something like @media at 70vh add filter:invert(1); not sure how I word it though, It needs to work on both image and text,

If anyone has any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using only css, you will have to use some JavaScript, here you have an example using jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var winVH = $(window).height();

  if (scroll >= winVH) {
    $(".yourNavClass").addClass("invertColor");
  } else {
    $(".yourNavClass").removeClass("invertColor");
  }
});
```

What that code do is to add a class to your nav when the scroll is >= to 100vh, so you can set the invertColor class to filter:invert(1) and that should do the trick, here you have some documentation about the scrollTop function https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Thanks man, used what you said only I put $(".logo, .hamburger") to be inverted instead of the whole nav bar as the nav background when the page loads is clear, doing it that way also means I have more control over the colour of the nav bar and it doesn't invert my side nav too. Thanks tho man such a clean way to do it!

Comment: Just wondering tho does it have to be 100vh? is it possible to have the transition at 70vh?

Comment: Your welcome! and yes you can do it, as you know now the height function we are using in the winVH variable gets the 100% of the viewport height, so what you can do is divided, for example "var winVH = $(window).height() / 2;" it's gonna be equal to 50vh, if you want a 70vh you can just do this "var winVH = $(window).height() / 1.40;"